Jupyter notebook lost syntax highlithing
After creating environments (ubuntu VM) Jupyter Notebook lost highlighting of code syntax for some reason. Highlighting is now unavailable for all environments. How to fix that? Below you can see my language syntax highlighting is grayed out and below how my code looks right now.



Opening Jupyter Lab shows me my code highlighted so I can work normally. I wonder why I can not see it in my regular notebook view...

Someone just posted a similar post here, especially since here and there syntax highlighting is fine in JupyterLab. I'm linking each via comments in case one gets a solution. This will lessen chance one thread becomes a silo, separate from reference to the other.
